# How to layout WPF controls to fill its parent when each other is collapsed

Tags: .net, wpf, layout

I have a UserControl with two different UserControls on it. Usually a GridPanel would do its job with a splitter between the controls.
Now, if one of the controls is collapsed - by data binding to a setting on the parent UserControl - the other one should stretch to the available space ... of course, vice versa.

Tried - and failed - solutions:

**GridPanel:**
The still visible control does not stretch because the row of the collapsed control is still there.

**DockPanel:**
There would be the possibility to collapse a top docked control, which would lead the filling control to stretch ... but not the other way.

Is there a simple way to achieve the described behaviour?

Comment: post your current XAML and a screenshot of what you have versus what you need.

Comment: You are setting the visibility to collapsed?

Answer (score 0):

You can control the container to get the desired behavior.
When both items are shown you can do this:

```
<RowDefinition Height="*" />
<RowDefinition Height="*" />
```

When you want only one to show you change it to this:

```
<RowDefinition Height="*" />
<RowDefinition Height="0" />
```

And when you want the other one to show you do this:

```
<RowDefinition Height="0" />
<RowDefinition Height="*" />
```

For an elegant solution you can bind the Height to the visibility value of the controls. Then you create a converter that returns a height of 0 if visibility is Collapsed or * if visibility is Visible:

```
        <Grid Height="200" Width="200">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="{Binding ElementName=TopControl, Path=Visibility, Converter={StaticResource VisibilityToHeightConverter}}" />
                <RowDefinition Height="{Binding ElementName=BottomControl, Path=Visibility, Converter={StaticResource VisibilityToHeightConverter}}" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <ContentControl Name="TopControl" />
            <ContentControl Name="BottomControl" Grid.Row="1" />
        </Grid>
```

Comment: I understand the meaning of your answer. But how do I get the controls to stretch over the available space (basically and after one of the controls is collapsed)?

Comment: I modified my answer to something new. Sorry it's a bit late and hope this helps.